# How can I mock some method calls of a bean but use the defined bean in other method calls in the same test class?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to test a Service Interface that has a specified implementation in a TestConfiguration.  The Service Interface gets DAO interface injected which also has a specified implementation in a TestConfiguration.  The implementation of the Service is defined as the real service that will be in production while the Test DAO is a new custom implementation of the interface.

In 95% of cases, I want to use the Test DAO Implementation.  However, in some tests I want to override the functionality of the DAO.  Since there are so few instances where I want to override the DAO I want to just mock using Mockito on a conditional basis without creating another implementation of the DAO Interface (for edge cases like returning an empty list from the DAO). Ideally, these would be in the same class that's dedicated to testing the Service.

I have tried using the @Spy annotation on the DAO Bean in the Test Class. I have tried using the @MockBean on the DAO bean. I have tried using Mockito's doReturn and when functionality to overwrite the DAO's default implementation, however, I always get back the result from the Test DAO implementation defined in the TestConfiguration.

I did change the text of what I am doing since it is company code, but this is exactly what I'm trying to do otherwise.

My TestConfiguration is defined like so

```java
@TestConfiguration
public class TestAppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PersonService personService() {
        return new PersonServiceImpl(personDao());
    }  

    @Bean
    public PersonDao personDao() {
        return new TestPersonDaoImpl();
    }
}
```

My Service Implementation is as follows

```java
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonServiceImpl.class);

    private PersonDao personDao;

    public PersonServiceImpl(PersonDao personDao){
        this.personDao = personDao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<PersonDto> getAllPersons() {
        return personDao.findAll().stream()
                .map(person -> PersonDtoFactory.getPersonDto(person))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public PersonDto getPersonById(Long id) {
       return PersonDtoFactory.getPersonDto(personDao.findById(id));

    }
}
```

My Test DAO Implementation is as follows

```java
public class TestPersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

    @Override
    public List<PersonModel> findAll() {
        return getPersons();
    }

    @Override
    public List<PersonModel> findById(id) {
        return getPersons().stream()
                       .filter(person -> person.getId() == id)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private List<PersonModel> getPersons() {
        List<PersonModel> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        personList.add(new PersonModel(1L, "Susan");
        personList.add(new PersonModel(2L, "Jerry");
        personList.add(new PersonModel(3L, "Tom");
        return personList;
    }
}
```

And then finally my service test class

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(TestAppConfiguration.class)
public class PersonServiceTests {
    //We won't test web socket functionality in this test class.
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @MockBean //want to overwrite in the test only when specified in the test, otherwise, use default TestPersonDaoImpl bean.
    private PersonDao personDao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllPersons() {
        assert(personService.getAllTests().size() > 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void getPersonById() {
        assert(personService.getPersonById(1L).getName().equals("Susan"));
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllPersons_NoPersons(){
        //Mock the DAO call since it will have all of the test data by default
        doReturn(new ArrayList<Person>()).when(personDao).findAll();
        //when(personDao.findAll()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());  <-- this also doesn't work
        assert(personService.getAllPersons().size() == 0);
}
```

Expected would be that all tests pass, and the DAO call would get overwritten when called in the service implementation.  The actual result is that the first two tests pass, and the third test fails because it does not overwrite the dao call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `@MockBean` you will get an injected mock instance.

With `@Spy` your dao will not get injected in the service

You need `@SpyBean`.. you will get the injection and all methods invoked as they are implemented by default.